# SSRS split date columns into years

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS table with a date column which I want to arrange into columns for different years, Where do I filter columns?
I have tried to filter the details group withe the following expression:

`=Year(Fields!Ontledingsdatum.Value) = year(now) -5`

But get the following error :

> Cannot compare data of types System.Boolean and System.String.

Also, I think putting the filter in the details group is incorrect.
Regards

Comment: Why not using matrix instead of table grouping on Year(Fields!Ontledingsdatum.Value)?

Answer (score 0):

From your error message it appears you are trying to do your comparison in the grouping expression.  This is not how grouping works.

Remove the `= year(now) -5` from your grouping expression and you will get groups that are based on the year of your `Ontledingsdatum` field.  If you only want to display the last 5 years of data, you will need to filter the data as well.

Ideally you would filter this in your dataset before the data is returned to your report.  If your dataset is SQL based, you can add `where Ontledingsdatum >= dateadd(yyyy,datediff(yyyy,0,getdate())-5,0)` to get all values from the start of the year 5 years ago.

If you need to filter in your SSRS report, you can add a filter to either your dataset or your table by adding a filter in the properties of the dataset or table (Not in the grouping) and specify that same filter as in the SQL.  Something like the following should do it:

Expression: `=Fields!Ontledingsdatum.Value`
Type:       `Date/Time`
Operator:   `>=`
Value:      `=cdate(year(now)-5 & "/01/01")`

Comment: Thank you. What I am trying to achieve is to have five columns for each year. Under each column only data for that year should be shown. Regards

Comment: @Gideon 5 columns got each year?  How are you splitting the year into five?

Comment: Hello iamdave. Yes I am splitting the year into five. I have done this already in sql. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Gideon  What do you mean by split into 5 though?  5 date groups or groups based on other data items like regions or customers?